# When terminal emulator exits, why does shell also exits?

Tags: shell, terminal, signals, terminal-emulator

When I start a terminal emulator (for example, qterminal), it starts the default shell (for example, bash). And when I quit the terminal (for example, by clicking the x button or by killing the terminal), the shell also exits. There remainds no process of the shell. I would like to know how this mechanism is implemented.

At first, I suspected that the terminal sends some signal to the shell. So I trap SIGQUIT, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP in the shell, but no signal was trapped. I have no idea other than signal.

It may depands on the terminal and the shell, and perhaps on the OS. Please tell me any information about this situation.

Comment: https://martin.uy/blog/how-terminal-emulators-work-on-linux/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The linked page explains how ctrl+c terminates a command. But, as far as I understood, it does not seem to explain how the shell is forced to exit. If it does, please tell me the part of the document.

Comment: Run the following command in the shell: `strace -f -o strace.log -p $$`. Then close the terminal, and check in the `strace.log` file which signal it received.

Comment: @user356126 You seem to have skipped quite a few parts of this article: "Bash runs as a child process of gnome-terminal, and yes as child process of bash." "Gnome-terminal, when launching a new window or tab, makes a request to the TTY driver* in the kernel asking for a new pseudo-terminal (PTY). " ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the terminal sends a hangup (SIGHUP) to the process. Additionally, when the terminal closes its 'master' end of the pty, certain processes attached to it automatically receive a SIGHUP from the kernel as well – whether the terminal sent one or not.

Though the signal from the kernel is not sent to all processes which have the pty as their controlling terminal – I haven't checked exactly, but I think it is delivered specifically just to the "foreground pgroup", basically the same as with SIGINT/SIGQUIT from Ctrl+C/Ctrl+\.

Shells themselves such as Bash already have a handler for SIGHUP which delivers additional SIGHUPs to all *background jobs* managed by the shell (ignoring those which were `disown`ed), e.g. a `sleep 1h &` will be SIGHUP'd by Bash when the latter is about to exit due to its own received SIGHUP.

For example, when closing the terminal cleanly:

```
$ sudo strace -p ${pid_of_bash}
strace: Process 102874 attached
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=87390, si_uid=1000} ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[...]
```

And when using a debugger to issue `close(ptmx_fd)` from the terminal's process:

```
$ sudo strace -p ${pid_of_bash}
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0])
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
ioctl(2, TCXONC, TCOON)                 = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
write(2, "\33[?2004l\r", 9)             = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

Finally, when the pty is closed, the shell (or other foreground program) will receive EOF when trying to read from it (i.e. `read()` will return 0), which it'll handle just as if you pressed Ctrl+D – this too will usually cause the program to exit, though of course it *could* ignore the EOF (I've seen a particular program go into an infinite loop in this case, when it decided to ignore both the SIGHUP *and* the EOF).

It is very possible that the shell exits on EOF *before* it reaches your custom SIGHUP handler. For example, I can reproduce your results in Bash under GNOME Terminal (with the `trap ... SIGHUP` not being called), *however,* if I additionally set `IGNOREEOF=1` telling Bash to not quit on EOF, then the custom SIGHUP trap is indeed invoked.

A custom trap also happens to *override* Bash's default "exit on SIGHUP" behavior. So when I tell Bash to ignore EOFs *and* trap SIGHUP, it actually keeps trying to print a prompt to a nonexistent tty – the 'strace' output shows it calling all of my usual PROMPT_COMMAND hooks, trying to write the prompt to stdout, getting EIO, then trying to write error messages to stderr, getting EIO from *that,* and only afterwards it decides that enough is enough and exits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your detailed explanation made me understand the exit behavior of Bash, and why I could not trap SIGHUP. Following your way, I set IGNOREEOF=1. Then, the cusdom SIGHUP trap was invoked also in my envoronment (Bash under qterminal).

Comment: I tried to check signals using strace. In my environment, it seems that Bash sends SIGHUP to itself, and that Bash handles several signals using rt_sigaction. I could not understand why Bash behaves like that, but it made me curious.